# How to speed up the search in Sphinx using negative words?

Tags: performance, search, sphinx

I need use sphinx search with negative  words, but if I use negative words speed of search is fall. If without negative words search is working good.
What I can do to tuning to sphinx for search with negative words ?
I need good speed search.
example of query:

"cat -dog -animal" - slow query

"cat" - fast query

The more negative words, the slower the search.
sphinx ver 2.2.11, config:

```
searchd
{
  dist_threads = 2
  listen            = 9312
  log               = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  query_log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
  read_timeout      = 5
  max_children      = 30
  pid_file          = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
  max_matches       = 1000000
  seamless_rotate   = 1
  preopen_indexes   = 1
  unlink_old        = 1
  binlog_path       = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is any magic config option that can speed up this as such.

The query can only be asked, by finding all the 'cat' documents. Then looping through each of dog and animal, and removing them. That takes time.

Maybe sharding would help
https://www.google.com/search?q=sphinx+search+shard
... it breaks down the query into parts, so it can be 'parallelized'